# Pro Series 2400 Sump Pump Alarm System

Tags: sump-pump

I am working on my brothers sump pump issues and I have hit a wall.  I have replaced the primary pump (new), I have replaced the battery (new) and I have checked to ensure that the secondary (back-up) pump operated correctly (it does).  After all this the WARNING ALARMS light keeps coming on and with an annoying beep.  This alarm light indicates that "The backup pump was activated.  Check the main pump for failure.  To silence the alarm during emergencies, press the button for 5 seconds."  How can I silence this alarm permanently knowing all systems are good???

Comment: Check the items on page 16: https://www.stopflooding.com/assets/2/6/Manual_PHCC-2400_2-18-2021.pdf *i.e.* a bad check valve is one possible cause. Float switch cord and AC cord being too close is another possible cause.

Comment: What brand/model pump is it? Without that info, trouble shooting might be a bit difficult.